# what is the command to add a Y coordinate name

Tags: dm-script

When we import the CSV line plot file to DM, what is the command /code to add a Y coordinate name? Such as intensity or counts etc.

```
string filename
dircontents.taggroupgettagasstring("["+i+"]:Name", filename)
string extension=pathextractextension(filename,0)
if(extension!="csv" && extension!="CSV" && extension!="txt" && extension!="TXT")
{
    result("\nSkipped file "+filename+". Files must be .csv or .txt")
                continue
}

string thisfilepath=pathconcatenate(directory, filename)
image array=ReadandDisplayCSV(thisfilepath, headerline) 
drawlineplot(array, headerline, filename, IncludeError)
```

Comment: What you're looking for is actually not a "Y-calibration" because DigitalMicrograph thinks of lineplots as 1-dimensional data. What you want to calibrate is the **intensity**, i.e. the actual data-values. This is what you see on the y-axis of lineplots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: LinePlot]

The commands - as documented in the F1 help at the end of the "image" chapter - are

`ImageSetIntensityScale`
`ImageSetIntensityOrigin`
`ImageSetIntensityUnitString`

[image: F1 help]

You use them as in the following example:

```
image linePlot := realImage( "Spectrum", 4, 200 )
linePlot = cos( icol/iwidth * 5 * Pi() ) + random()*0.1
linePlot.ShowImage()
OKDialog( "Add X calibration" )
linePlot.ImageSetDimensionCalibration( 0, 100, 0.5, "eV" , 0 ) 

OKDialog( "Add intensity calibration" )
linePlot.ImageSetIntensityScale( 0.5 ) 
linePlot.ImageSetIntensityOrigin( 100 ) 
linePlot.ImageSetIntensityUnitString( "counts" )
```